# drawImage() to canvas in a sequence and maintain the sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have set 6 canvas elements on my page. There is a `<input type="file">` button placed to add an image. Each time a students image is added it should display wihtin the canvas specs and placed from left to right in a sequence.

I can not seem to get the images placed from left to right.

example: 1st added image should be in "can1", 2nd added image should be in "can2", 3rd added image in "can3". If "can2" image is deleted "can3" should move to position of "can2".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way would be to store each of the images in an array then anytime an image is added/removed, redraw each of the canvases.

```
var images = [],
    contexts = [ // collection of the canvas drawing contexts ];
function refreshCanvases() {
    for (var i = 0, len = contexts.length; i < len; i++) {
        var context = contexts[i],
            image = images[i];
        // I'm assuming you have width/height defined somewhere else
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        if (image) {
            context.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
}

function addImage() {
    // Code for loading image...
    images.push(image);
    refreshCanvases();
}
```

And lather, rinse, repeat for removing images.